# how i can apply an if confition on a field of formBuilder.group Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, formbuilder

Im trying to use **if condition** instead of **? :** for the filed **booleanInput** using Angular but i don't khow how.

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
        this.parameterForm = this.formBuilder.group({
            booleanInput:
                this.ppf.type === 'boolean'
                    ? this.finalValue=== undefined
                        ? (this.finalValue= false)
                        : this.finalValue
                    : false
        });
    }
```

I did several searches but found nothing.
Can someone help me please ?

Comment: It is very unclear what you want to achieve. Please give a better example with more insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand, You wanna assign this control a value i.e. `false` or `true`. You can do this by the following improvements. Might be helpful. Thanks

```js
 ngOnInit(): void {
 let finalValue;
 if(this.ppf.type === 'boolean') {
  if(finalValue === undefined) {
    finalValue = false
  } else {
    finalValue = this.finalValue
  }
 } else {
  finalValue = false;
 }
        this.parameterForm = this.formBuilder.group({
            booleanInput: finalValue
        });
    }
```